# Create date from yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a function in which I pass a date:

```
createDate("2016-12-24'T'17:12:33.0500")
```

and the definition

```
func createDate(fromString: String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    guard let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fromString) else {
        return NSDate()
    }
    return date
}
```

For some reason I always get today's date instead of 24 december.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that the source string has single quotes around the `T`?

Answer (score 1):

change the dateformat to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
```

and change input to

```
createDate("2016-12-24T17:12:33.0500")
```

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me,you can try

Note: your passing datestring not contain Z at last. 
you use

```
createDate("2016-12-24'T'17:12:33.0500")
```

try like this

```
createDate("2016-12-24'T'17:12:33.050Z")//3 digit in millisecond part , not 4

 func createDate(dateString:String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    dateFormater.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    return dateFormater.dateFromString(dateString)!
}
```

Comment: still returning today's date in playground :(

Comment: In millisecond part  why you have 4 digit .0500, it will be 3 digit .500 or .050 , millisecond is 1/1000 part of a second , so millisecond can be only 999, max 3 digit ,

Comment: or you can add another S on format, i am not sure about that , hope you will find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your input has no time zone (example: "+000") but four digits of milliseconds. To handle this change your date format to:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
```

Also remove `'` around "T" in the input:

```
"2016-12-24T17:12:33.0500"
```

Together:

```
func createDate(fromString: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: fromString) else {
        return Date()
   }
   return date
}
createDate(fromString: "2016-12-24T17:12:33.0500")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSDate*)fetchDateFromString:(NSString*)strDate {

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [df setLocale:usLocale];

    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    [df setTimeZone:gmt];
     NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:strDate];
    if (date) {
        return date;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Attention!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! - Date format is not valid");
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
        date = [df dateFromString:strDate];
        if (date) {
            return date;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I AM USING THIS IN SWIFT 3.1

func convertDateStringToDate(longDate: String) -> String{

```
    /* INPUT: longDate = "2017-01-27T05:00:00.000Z"
     * OUTPUT: "1/26/17"
     * date_format_you_want_in_string from
     * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
     */

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: longDate)

    if date != nil {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        let dateShort = formatter.string(from: date!)

        return dateShort

    } else {

        return longDate

    }
}
```